# In the way or the way

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs

> “Eat the Greek way”

vs.

> “Eat in the Greek way”

1. Are these sentences both correct?
2. Have they the same meaning?
3. Is there a difference in the grammar structure?
4. Is there a rule that explains when to use the preposition “in”
       before “way”?

Answer (score 1):

For the phrase you are using as an example, usually "***in***" is not used

> Eat the Greek way

The slight nuance between your two examples might be

> Eat the Greek way

means to eat exactly as Greeks eat, whereas

> Eat **in** the Greek way

may mean to eat in a *similar fashion* as Greeks eat but not exactly as Greeks eat.